# Reader View for clutter-free Design

Tags: html, css, browser, semantic-markup

Are there any Guidelines to do Reader View Design? 
I've been looking for documentation about it, and I find nothing recent, a lot of discussion about having no standard established...

I want to enable the site to be able to visualize in a nice way on Kindle, Tablet reader mode, terminal browsers, reader mode, and printing mode.

The printing is covered, and the source order, it's also pretty intelligent, but the readability and semantics is what I'm not sure, about.

I have basically this, and the source order for the elements in each part of the article it's also carefully thought so I can visualize it correctly with no CSS, but, now I'm starting to worry about Readers like Firefox and Safari mode.

This could be a snippet of what I currently have: (What I have is slightly more complex)

```
<body>
  <header>SiteHeader</header>
  <nav>site navegation</nav>
  <main>
      <nav>Content Nav</nav>
      <article>
         <header>Post Header and Few Meta</header>
         <section>Post Body</section>
         <footer>Footer Notes, and few meta</footer>
      </article>
  </main>
  <footer>Site Footer</footer>
</body>
```

So the question is this:
I feel that this design is "smart enough" semantic-wise to have a nice render, and crawled, but how can I ensure, It's actually as Smart as I think, and validate the Reader View Display?